# moderncv - newline within a cventry

Tags: line-breaking, moderncv

The information that I want to provide isn't fitting into one line.
I am working with

```
\cventry{}{}{}{}...
```

I want to put information into a new line, still positioned to what is in the line above. I tried to put `\\` or `\newline` into/between the brackets but it was not working.

Comment: I managed to do what I was looking for: I just put \newline{} and into the brackets what I wanted to have in that new line.

Answer (score 15):

I tested with `moderncv.cls 2012/03/26 v1.0`, and `\newline` works and generates a line break in every argument. This can be easily tested with `template.tex` which is distributed with the `moderncv` documentation - just a crazy test of line breaks:

```
\section{Education}
\cventry{2010\newline -- 2012}{Master of Science\newline (honoris causa)}
  {University of TeXas\newline TeX committee}
  {Austin\newline (``Keep Austin Weird'')}
  {Supported by\newline the local TUG}
  {Awarded for writing\newline the thesis in \LaTeX}
```

[image: cv example section]

Indeed `\\` doesn't work, but `\newline` does. And, in such and similar cases, you could use `\parbox`. Within that, even `\\` works.

The first argument is an exception: within that, `\\` works and gives properly right aligned lines, in contrast to `\newline`:

```
\cventry{2010\\ -- 2012}...
```